# ¿Cómo calcular sub total imponible y no imponible con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una devolución de llamada realizada con Ajax la cual vinculo a una tabla de datos dinámica. Tengo un `<input>` que señala como impuesto definido por una clase del mismo nombre, cuando es imponible recupera el valor 1, cuando no lo es el valor es 0.

Deseo sumar todos los subtotales imponibles y los no imponibles y luego colocar por separado en dos `<inputs>`. Con el código siguiente no he conseguido el resultado, por favor espero su apoyo.

Éste es el código:

```
$.each(obj, function(i,item){
  $('#tableDetalle').append(
    '<tr>'+
        '<td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminarItem('+item.idItems+')">Eliminar</button></td>'+
        '<td width="100"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="'+item.codigo+'" name="rptSKU" id="rptSKU" readonly></td> '+
        '<td width="400"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="'+item.nombre+'" name="rptDESCRIPCION" id="rptDESCRIPCION" readonly></td> '+
        '<td width="200"><input type="text" class="form-control cantidad" value="'+item.cantidad+'" name="rptCANTIDAD" id="rptCANTIDAD" ></td> '+
        '<td width="200"><input type="text" class="form-control precio" value="'+item.precioUnitario+'" name="rptPU" id="rptPU" ></td> '+
        '<td width="50"><input type="text" class="form-control impuesto" value="'+item.impuesto+'" name="rptIMPUESTO" id="rptIMPUESTO" ></td> '+
        '<td width="200"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control descuento" value="'+item.descuento+'" name="rptDESCUENTO" id="rptDESCUENTO"></td> '+
        '<td width="200"><input type="text" class="form-control subtotal" name="rptSUBTOTAL" id="rptSUBTOTAL" readonly></td> '+
    '</tr>'
  );
  var subtotalnoimponible = 0;
  var subtotalimponible = 0;
  var i = $('.subtotal').index(this);
  var cant    = $('.cantidad:eq('+i+')').val();
  var precio  = $('.precio:eq('+i+')').val();
  var subtotal = parseFloat(cant) * parseFloat(precio);
  $('.subtotal:eq('+i+')').val(subtotal.toFixed(2));
  if ($('.impuesto').val() === '1'){
    subtotalimponible+=parseFloat($(this).val());
    $('#subtotalimponible').val(subtotalimponible.toFixed(2));
  }else{
    subtotalnoimponible+=parseFloat($(this).val());
    $('#subtotalnoimponible').val(subtotalnoimponible.toFixed(2));
  }
});//each
```

Se espera este resultado:
[image: Explicación gráfica]

Comment: Por favor, proporciónanos un valor de `obj` con el que reproducir tu problema y trabajar, así como el HTML necesario para hacer funcionar tu pequeño trozo de código. Eso nos facilitará la tarea de ayudarte. Pásate por [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Gracias.

Comment: Asi es como se ve:    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: baseurl + "compras/getProductosDetalle",
            data:idCompras,
            success: function( data ) {
              var obj = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: Nosotros no podemos ejecutar esa llamada XHR (ajax), por lo que nos vendría bien un ejemplo para poder reproducir el código.

Comment: @OscarGarcia edite la pregunta en la cual añado un gráfico del resultado esperado. La idea es sumar solo los valores coincidente para cada fila donde el condicionante es el campo de impueto.

Comment: Un valor de `obj` hubiera sido de agradecer, pero bueno, en cuanto pueda te redacto una respuesta.

Comment: Si es lo que necesitas házmelo saber para extender la respuesta con enlaces de interés para explicarte aquellas llamadas en las que tengas dudas (como el cambio de `.val()` a `.text()`, etc). Si no es lo que buscas, dime qué le falta para que lo complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En los comentarios te dejo detalles sobre los cambios que he hecho:

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th>Eli</th>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Nombre</th>
<th>Cantidad</th>
<th>Precio</th>
<th>Impuesto</th>
<th>?</th>
<th>Subtotal</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody id="tableDetalle"></tbody>
</table>
<p>Inponible: <span id="subtotalimponible">0</span></p>
<p>No imponible: <span id="subtotalnoimponible">0</span></p>
<script>
var obj = [
  {
    codigo: 1,
    nombre: 'Prueba 1',
    cantidad: 3,
    precioUnitario: 23.5,
    impuesto: 1,
  },
  {
    codigo: 2,
    nombre: 'Prueba 2',
    cantidad: 1,
    precioUnitario: 7.25,
    impuesto: 0,
  },
  {
    codigo: 1,
    nombre: 'Prueba 1',
    cantidad: 2,
    precioUnitario: 102.95,
    impuesto: 1,
  },
];
/* Estos son datos globales, no de cada iteración */
var subtotalnoimponible = 0;
var subtotalimponible = 0;
/* Primero generamos los datos */
$.each(obj, function(i, item) {
  /* Tenemos los datos en "item", ¿para qué buscarlos en el DOM? */
  var subtotal = item.cantidad * item.precioUnitario;
  if (item.impuesto === 1) {
    subtotalimponible += subtotal;
  } else {
    subtotalnoimponible += subtotal;
  }
  $('#tableDetalle').append(
    '<tr>'+
        '<td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminarItem('+item.idItems+')">Eliminar</button></td>'+
        '<td width="100"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="'+item.codigo+'" name="rptSKU" id="rptSKU" readonly></td> '+
        '<td width="400"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="'+item.nombre+'" name="rptDESCRIPCION" id="rptDESCRIPCION" readonly></td> '+
        '<td width="200"><input type="text" class="form-control cantidad" value="'+item.cantidad+'" name="rptCANTIDAD" id="rptCANTIDAD" ></td> '+
        '<td width="200"><input type="text" class="form-control precio" value="'+item.precioUnitario+'" name="rptPU" id="rptPU" ></td> '+
        '<td width="50"><input type="text" class="form-control impuesto" value="'+item.impuesto+'" name="rptIMPUESTO" id="rptIMPUESTO" ></td> '+
        '<td width="200"><input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control descuento" value="'+item.descuento+'" name="rptDESCUENTO" id="rptDESCUENTO"></td> '+
        '<td width="200"><input type="text" class="form-control subtotal" name="rptSUBTOTAL" id="rptSUBTOTAL" readonly value="' + subtotal + '"></td> '+
    '</tr>'
  );
});
/* Para campos que no sean "select", "radio", etc se usa text para modificar el contenido */
$('#subtotalimponible').text(subtotalimponible.toFixed(2));
$('#subtotalnoimponible').text(subtotalnoimponible.toFixed(2));
</script>
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias por la respuesta. Es lo que esperaba.